# How can I change the folder icon for the Google Drive for Desktop folder?

Tags: external-hard-drive, google-drive, favicon

I'm using Windows, and I want to put a custom icon, .png or .ico, on this Google Drive Folder. (Currently it's named ANNA, but it'll be changed)

[image]

This is a drive that leads directly to my Google Drive. I currently have Google Drive for Desktop installed, and I want to change the icon here. The autorun.inf method is not supported.

Any idea on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Win+R and type regedit, and press enter. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons. Create a new key called the drive letter (G), and in that key create another key called "DefaultIcon". Modify the "(Default)" string, and set it to the full path of an .ico file. (from https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/74659-change-drive-icon-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: It works. Thanks! :)